# Can't compile with Android 2.2

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, compilation, apk

I am struggling with the compilation of my Android projects. Whenever I try to create a Android project I can't seem to compile it for Android 2.2/2.3.3. I set the minimum required SDK to API 8 and the target is 10. But when I want to compile it for 2.2/2.3.3 it just isn't in the list like the picture below.

[image]

Now I search on the internet for solutions and I can't seem to find one. I downloaded the android bundle from the android website which includes all the needed files etc.

I used the SDK Manager to install 2.2 and 2.3.3:

[image]

I can get the project running on my 4.0.3 emulator, just because also can't make a 2.2 or 2.3.3 emulator. I compiled the project to `.apk` and tested it on a 2.2 phone but it can't install it.

Does anyone has a solution for this? You would be a hero.

Comment: Couldn't get...what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: I don't really get any errors, but eclipse and the Virtual Device Manager can't seem to find the Android 2.2 or/and 2.3.3 sdk's

Comment: At first pic, it seems that you do not have 2.x.x apis. How about to download them ? To compile with 2.x.x, you should have the apis. Use SDK manager to download them. If you have, be sure to installed apis and your eclipse apis are at same directory.

Comment: Did you opened sdk manager from eclipse or directly from path? This is coz I had similar issue when I was installing sdk.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your `sdk`. It is very important that you do. SDK Manager will show you what are the components you haven't installed. Mark them and install. Now check whether the path of `java` and `SDK` is set properly. After doing all this try again to compile. I think it should. if not post the error you are getting and your manifest file too.